# Is it possible to trigger jquery tispy tooltip based on results of an ajax call?

Tags: jquery, triggers, tipsy

Im doing an ajax call, that does the following on success:

```
success: function(data) {
var allok= data.success;
if(allok == true) {
   $("#share_text").addClass('share_success').delay(2000).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("share_success");
      next();
   });
} else {
   $("#share_text").addClass('share_fail').delay(2000).queue(function(next){
     $(this).removeClass("share_fail");
     next();
   });
}
   $('#share_message').html(data.message);
   $("#share_submit").val("Share");
   $("#share_submit").removeAttr("disabled")
}
```

Where `allok = false` (the else block) it should trigger the tipsy tooltip below this text box, while its doing addClass/removeClass.

```
<input name="whatever_name" id="share_text" type="text" value="Blah blah" size="40" title="This is a tooltip">
```

If I add `$('#share_text').tipsy('show')` into the else block, it works only when you mouseover the text box. How do I get it to show by itself?

Comment: i don't understand what is the question. Can you be more precise?

Comment: The tooltip should appear below the html input box if the ajax request returns false in the allok variable.

Comment: You can trigger a tooltip manually using `.tipsy("show")` and `.tipsy("hide")`. More details in the [manual](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/).

Comment: I tried that, it still only shows onmouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cant you simply use the jquery trigger() function ?

```
$('#share_text').trigger('mouseenter'); // to show it
$('#share_text').trigger('mouseleave'); // to hide it
```

Don't forget to first attach the tipsy() behaviour to #share_text before running the above code.

```
$('#share_text').tipsy();
```

In your code it should look like this:

```
$(function(){

// things to do on document.ready:
$('#share_text').tipsy();
// ... more stuff

// ... until your ajax callback
success: function(data) {
var allok= data.success;
if(allok == true) {
   $("#share_text").addClass('share_success').delay(2000).queue(function(next){
      $(this).removeClass("share_success");
      next();
   });
} else {
   $("#share_text").addClass('share_fail').delay(2000).queue(function(next){
     $(this).removeClass("share_fail");
     next();
   });
}
   $('#share_message').html(data.message);
   $("#share_submit").val("Share");
   $("#share_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
// simulate a mouseenter event on share_text, to launch tipsy().show
   $('#share_text').trigger('mouseenter');
}
```

Comment: It already does this by default. I need to show it without user's interaction. When the ajax response is false for allok variable, the tooltip should show, which will display the error message of what the user did wrong

Comment: trigger('mouseenter') will launch the tipsy.show() method. It will simulates a "mouseenter" event, which is basically what hover is.

Comment: i've included my code into yours. Hopefully you'll get the point.

Comment: post a sample of what you got so far on jsbin.com and publish back the link to your prototype here, so that i can get a better insight at what you are trying to do.